# Excel not recognising XLS files

Tags: excel, xls

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the above. I installed Office365 on a new computer recently and Excel does not recognise XLS files. These are handled by Office XLS Handler by default.
I can open the XLS files in Excel only by opening it through another file.
I tried changing default app for handling XLS to Excel in the Settings but it doesn't even see Excel on the list.

Many thanks,
Agata

Comment: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can browse and choose Excel if it's not showing Excel in the default list.

**Edited**:
The path of Excel in Windows 7 is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15

Comment: Hi Abhishek, excel doesn't show when browsing either.

Comment: this may help... https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-customize/i-would-like-to-know-where-excelexe-is-located/3f1503b5-dd4a-4ccb-84cb-7dbf95127dda